# foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given

Tags: database, laravel

I'm on laravel 8, and got this problem when I want to show my data from database based on it's category id. And I'm pretty sure that I already assign the data with the category.

**My Index.Blade**

```
@extends('layouts.front')

@section('content')

    <div class="container">
        <h2>Produk {{ $categoryName ?? null }}</h2>

        <div class="custom-row-2">
            @foreach ($produks as $produk)

                @include('produk._single_product')

            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>

@endsection
```

**My Controller**

```
public function index()
    {
        $keranjangItems = \Cart::session(auth()->id())->getContent();

        $categoryId = request('category_id');
        $categoryName = null;

        if($categoryId){
            $category = Category::find($categoryId);
            $categoryName = ucfirst($category->name);

            $produks = $category->products;
        }else{
            $produks = Produk::take(10)->get();
        }


        return view('produk.index', compact('keranjangItems', 'produks', 'categoryName'));
    }
```

I found a thread with pretty much the same issue. Also I got this code from some tutorial I found on youtube, and it should works. I tried to clear cache, add "(array)" in the foreach. And none of them works, can anyone help me please? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is probably the problem.

`$produks = $category->products;`

Is `products()` correctly defined as a relationship in the `Category` model? If it's not, `$category->products` will return `null`.

Comment: ahh I see, I did some changes for some of the variables, and apparently got confused while following the tutorial. thanks man